# Newtonsoft - World Weather Online. Troubles with retrieving a value from JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following issue: I deserialize JSON from World Weather Online successfully

```
private void Parse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
    ProgressBarRequest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Minsk&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
}
```

.. where xxxxxxxx is my API key.

Then I successfully deserialize the whole thing

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      try
      {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
         {
              var weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Result);
              Debug.WriteLine(weather);
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      }
      finally
      {
         ProgressBarRequest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
      }
}
```

I retrieve the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "current_condition": [
      {
        "cloudcover": "0",
        "humidity": "51",
        "observation_time": "06:51 PM",
        "precipMM": "0.0",
        "pressure": "1021",
        "temp_C": "15",
        "temp_F": "59",
        "visibility": "10",
        "weatherCode": "113",
        "weatherDesc": [
          {
            "value": "Clear"
          }
        ],
        "weatherIconUrl": [
          {
            "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png"
          }
        ],
        "winddir16Point": "NNE",
        "winddirDegree": "30",
        "windspeedKmph": "7",
        "windspeedMiles": "4"
      }
    ],
    "request": [
      {
        "query": "Minsk, Belarus",
        "type": "City"
      }
    ],
    "weather": [
      {
        "date": "2014-04-19",
        "precipMM": "0.0",
        "tempMaxC": "21",
        "tempMaxF": "71",
        "tempMinC": "8",
        "tempMinF": "47",
        "weatherCode": "113",
        "weatherDesc": [
          {
            "value": "Sunny"
          }
        ],
        "weatherIconUrl": [
          {
            "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
          }
        ],
        "winddir16Point": "E",
        "winddirDegree": "80",
        "winddirection": "E",
        "windspeedKmph": "17",
        "windspeedMiles": "10"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

... as seen from my Debug.WriteLine.

Ultimately, I'm trying to get the `temp_C` value from `current_condition`.

However, all my efforts so far have been a failure. In particular, the following piece of code:

```
Current_Condition weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Current_Condition>(e.Result);
Debug.WriteLine(weather.temp_C);
```

... returns `0` when I perform `Debug.WriteLine(weather.temp_C)`.

Here are the respective classes:

```
public class LocalWeatherInput
{
      public string query { get; set; }
      public string format { get; set; }
      public string extra { get; set; }
      public string num_of_days { get; set; }
      public string date { get; set; }
      public string fx { get; set; }
      public string cc { get; set; }
      public string includelocation { get; set; }
      public string show_comments { get; set; }
      public string callback { get; set; }
}
public class LocalWeather
{
      public Data data;
}
public class Data
{
      public List<Current_Condition> current_Condition;
      public List<Request> request;
      public List<Weather> weather;
}
      public class Current_Condition
{
      public DateTime observation_time { get; set; }
      public DateTime localObsDateTime { get; set; }
      public int temp_C { get; set; }
      public int windspeedMiles { get; set; }
      public int windspeedKmph { get; set; }
      public int winddirDegree { get; set; }
      public string winddir16Point { get; set; }
      public string weatherCode { get; set; }
      public List<WeatherDesc> weatherDesc { get; set; }
      public List<WeatherIconUrl> weatherIconUrl { get; set; }
      public float precipMM { get; set; }
      public float humidity { get; set; }
      public int visibility { get; set; }
      public int pressure { get; set; }
      public int cloudcover { get; set; }
}  
public class Request
{
      public string query { get; set; }
      public string type { get; set; }
}
public class Weather
{
      public DateTime date { get; set; }
      public int tempMaxC { get; set; }
      public int tempMaxF { get; set; }
      public int tempMinC { get; set; }
      public int tempMinF { get; set; }
      public int windspeedMiles { get; set; }
      public int windspeedKmph { get; set; }
      public int winddirDegree { get; set; }
      public string winddir16Point { get; set; }
      public string weatherCode { get; set; }
      public List<WeatherDesc> weatherDesc { get; set; }
      public List<WeatherIconUrl> weatherIconUrl { get; set; }
      public float precipMM { get; set; }
}
public class WeatherDesc
{
      public string value { get; set; }
}

      public class WeatherIconUrl
{
      public string value { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do to get the proper value of temp_C?

Comment: Doesnt e.Result contain the root object, data? And if so would you be doing something like Weather.data.currentCondition[x].temp_c  ?

Comment: Have a mooch in the immediate window at what lives in weather. If deserialisation is succesful into your object graph, you should be able to walk it v.easily.

Comment: Ah, just looked again. Try deserialising like so LocalWeather weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocalWeather>(e.Result);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not working because you are deserializing into the wrong class.  The `Current_Condition` is not at the root of your JSON, but you are treating it as if it were.  You need to deserialize into the `LocalWeather` class instead, then retrieve the data from that.

```
LocalWeather weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocalWeather>(e.Result);
Current_Condition currentCondition = weather.data.current_Condition[0];
Debug.WriteLine(currentCondition.temp_C);
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question so I get this correctly. In my classes there are lists within lists. The example of it would be Data/Weather(list)/WeatherDesc(another list)/value. Ultimately I'd like to access the `value` in `WeatherDesc` and `Debug.WriteLine()` it. How would I do that (i.e. how to access a value from a list which itself is in a list)? Thank you!

Comment: `WeatherDesc weatherlist = weather.data.weather[0].weatherDesc[0];` did the trick)